# Run PHP script in background without open it in browser

Tags: php

Can we run PHP script just like jar's files.I want to execute PHP script in background without open it in browser.Is this thing possible ?

Comment: Use the command line, eg `php path/to/your/script.php`

Comment: What operating system are you running

Comment: Use terminal to execute or a CRON for background job

Comment: @Phil :In that they are asking open with ..not executing that file.

Comment: @Aanshi Sorry, I don't understand your comment at all :(

Comment: @Phil I execute the php file using cmd.In that when I enter filename its asking open with which tool or s/w and then its just download that file.

Comment: @Aanshi Ah, so the PHP file is remote (as in, not on your local machine). In that case, use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)

Comment: @phil No that file is on local m/c

Answer (score 0):

Using Crons we can run. Make a batch file with php commands and run it through task scheduler if you are using windows OS or run it as cron for apache.